# How to implement a progress-bar in a backup script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, progress-bar, backup

I have a script which i can do a backup of entire system, but i can't see at what progress it is. I found many answers with progress-bar scripts but i don't know how to implement them into my backup script.

My backup script:

```
#!/bin/bash

Backup_system="Backup_$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tar.gz"

# Record start time by epoch second
start=$(date '+%s')

# List of excludes in a bash array, for easier reading.
excludes=(--exclude=/$Backup_system)
excludes+=(--exclude=/proc)
excludes+=(--exclude=/lost+found)
excludes+=(--exclude=/sys)
excludes+=(--exclude=/mnt)
excludes+=(--exclude=/media)
excludes+=(--exclude=/dev)

if ! tar -czf "$Backup_system" "${excludes[@]}" /; then
  status="tar failed"
elif ! mv "$Backup_system" ~/Backups ; then
  status="mv failed"
else
  status="success: size=$(stat -c%s ~/Backups/$Backup_system) duration=$((`date '+%s'` - $start))"
fi

# Log to system log; handle this using syslog(8).
logger -t Backup_system "$status"
```

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pv, to make a progress bar for every file, as explained here:
https://superuser.com/questions/168749/is-there-a-way-to-see-any-tar-progress-per-file

Comment: I already tried but it doesn't work with another script... (i tried "pv ./Backup.sh" )

Comment: @Mario Well this is not exactly what the response says, for example `tar cf - /folder-with-big-files -P | pv -s $(du -sb /folder-with-big-files | awk '{print $1}') | gzip > big-files.tar.gz`

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Mario pv won't work passing the script as argument, but using pipe with tar may work

Comment: With "pv | ./Backup.sh" starts only a time counter  " 0 B 0:00:19 [   0 B/s] [<=> " ... like this it is useless

Comment: @Mario I know, this is because pv must get data from STDIN in order to show a progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

No need to complicate things with `pv`, although very nice, it makes the throughput suffer a bit. A much better solution is using tar's own function called `--checkpoint=` and `--checkpoint-action`, like this:

```bash
tar -p -b1024 --record-size=1K --checkpoint=.100 --zstd -cf ${FNAME} ${DNAME}
```

See tar [manual here](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/checkpoints.html).